# Create View That Combines All Records From Identically Formatted Tables Across Arbitrary Number of Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We are using SQL Server to store production data that is generated daily by a test and measurement system. Every day a new user-defined database is generated by that tool in the dbo schema, and each database has only a single, identically-formatted table named "results" which may contain thousands of results.

If possible, I'd like to create a view that combines all of the "results" tables spread across all of the user-defined databases into a single universal table. In principle I feel that I know how to do this but the fact that the number of user-defined databases is arbitrary is where I'm getting tripped up, and I'm not even sure if this is possible to put something dynamic like this into a create view statement.  If not, it seems like this could be done with a stored procedure that dynamically generates this view at runtime, so that this procedure could be run right before querying the combined results.  I also realize that performance might be poor.

Here's where I'm at so far.  I can easily get a table that contains the 3-part name of each of the user-defined database tables with this code snippet:

---

```
SELECT [name] + '.dbo.results'
FROM sys.databases
WHERE [name] NOT IN ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb')
```

---

Let's just say that the output of this query is:

> database1.dbo.results
>
> database2.dbo.results
>
> ...

I can also manually type the create view statement that creates the type of view I want with:

---

```
USE master
GO
CREATE VIEW Combined_Results AS
SELECT * FROM database1.dbo.results
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM database2.dbo.results
...
```

---

What I'm hopeless at is automating the generation of this second SQL statement from the results of the first.  It seems that it should be easy but I'm just getting started with dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must say, firstly, that this is an extremely bad design. The number of databases is going to build up, and ideally the data should really be in one big table.

So you can create the view, as you have asked, or you can move the data to somewhere more sensible.

### Creating and maintaining the view

**You can use dynamic SQL to create this view.** You need to make sure to quote the names correctly using `QUOTENAME`

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW Combined_Results AS ' +
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST('
SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.results'
      AS nvarchar(max)), '
UNION ALL '
     )
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE [name] NOT IN ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb')
);

EXEC (@sql);
```

You can place this in an SQL Server Agent job, and have it execute every time a new database comes in.

---

### Moving the data to a new table

A much better idea is to transfer the data over. Create a new table with the same schema, plus an extra `CreationDate` column. Then we can use an Agent job to transfer the data over and delete the other database

```sql
DECLARE @dbname sysname =
(SELECT QUOTENAME(d.name)
FROM sys.databases d
WHERE [name] LIKE 'WhateverMatchingName%');

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
INSERT YourTable WITH (TABLOCKX)
  (CreationDate, OtherColumns)
SELECT GETDATE(), OtherColumns
FROM ' + @dbname + '.dbo.results WITH (TABLOCKX);
';

EXEC (@sql);

SET @sql = 'DROP DATABASE ' + @dbname;

EXEC (@sql);
';
```

Comment: This works great.  Thanks also for the advice concerning design and performance.  I agree that this is the sort of thing that shouldn't be done assuming you have full control.  I really like the idea using the agent to run the second option as a stored procedure whenever a new database hits.  That's about as tidy as I could hope for given the circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

i hope it suits you.

```
declare @QueryText nVarChar(max)

select @QueryText=Left(QueryText, Len(QueryText)-11)
from (
select Concat(Case When object_id(N'dbo.Combined_Results', N'V') Is Not 
Null Then 'ALTER' Else 'CREATE' End, N' VIEW dbo.Combined_Results AS ', 
char(13) + char(10), (
select Concat(N'SELECT * FROM [', name, N'].dbo.results', char(10), 
N'Union All', 
char(10)) AS [text()]
from sys.databases
where [name] not in ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb') 
for xml path (''))) As QueryText) As t

exec sp_executesql @QueryText
```

Comment: Thanks Anton - I gave it a shot but I'm getting syntax errors:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Combined_Results, Line 2 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near '-'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Combined_Results, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near '-'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Combined_Results, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near '-'.


I think I mostly follow this code but I'm a bit mystified by the "Len(QueryText)-11)" statement.  Are you removing the "UNION ALL" from the final generated select statement?

Comment: You are welcome. A database name should be enclosed in brackets. Expression "Len(QueryText)-11)" cuts off the trailing "Union all". I've edited the query.

Comment: If you have databases running on SQL Server instance with version 2017 or above It will be more elegant to use function "STRING_AGG".

Comment: It works great now.  Thanks for you your help and advice.  I've selected the answer below by Charlieface because it also incorporates the STRING_AGG suggestion you made which clean up the code, and also provides a good alternative with an explanation of the design considerations, but your post certainly deserves an upvote, and would be helpful to anyone working with SQL Server versions prior to 2017.  Thanks again!